# How do you import components having same name but in different folder in app.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

How can I manage same name component in different folder structure.

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('header', require('./components/Header.vue').default);
Vue.component('header', require('./components/site1/Header.vue').default);
Vue.component('header', require('./components/site2/Header.vue').default);


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

I am developing hmvc structure in laravel. I am using Caffeinated package for modules. So, different view for all module so i want to create multiple same name componet file in different folder.

How can i manage this ?

```
Vue.component('header', require('./components/Header.vue').default);
Vue.component('header', require('./components/site1/Header.vue').default);
Vue.component('header', require('./components/site2/Header.vue').default);
```

Comment: You either need to give them different names or use local components rather than registering them globally.

Comment: Yes, Last option is this, I write prefix before header file. But i want to find another proper way.

Comment: Are you using these `header` components inside other vue components or inside blade files?

Comment: @Rwd, I am planing to use this different header file in different module blade file.

Comment: In that case it might be worth creating different js files for the different sections/modules of your application.

Comment: I have tried to create js file inside module folder but it's calling outside app.js file component. I am using Caffeinated package for modules (HMVC)

Answer (score 0):

You should just allocate the components a new name during import as follows:

```
Vue.component('header-one', require('./components/Header.vue').default);
Vue.component('header-two', require('./components/site1/Header.vue').default);
Vue.component('header-three', require('./components/site2/Header.vue').default);
```

Better, to improve performance of your app, you can lazy load your components as follows:

```
Vue.component('header-one', () => import('./components/Header.vue'));
Vue.component('header-two', () => import('./components/site1/Header.vue'));
Vue.component('header-three', () => import('./components/site2/Header.vue'));
```

Comment: I have tried this code and got mentioned error. Reason: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.

Comment: @DwarkeshSoni that's just cache issue. Please clear your cache, if you're using webpack, be sure to use hash the file names so that they can be unique.

Comment: I have done cache clear and also watch command is already run. Sam error showing.